# Computing MSE per row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, mse

I have the below dataframe with many columns- `2016_x`, `2016_y`, `2017_x`, etc,
where `x` represents my actual values and `y` represents the forecast values.

How would I compute the mean squared error (MSE) row-wise to see it for different fruits.
Here is the below code-

```
import pandas as pd
s={'Fruits':['Apple','Mango'],'2016_x':[2,3],'2017_x':[4,5],'2018_x':[12,13],'2016_y':[3,4],'2017_y':[3,4],'2018_y':[12,13]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
```

This is how the dataframe looks like-
[image]

The desired output should show MSE of Apple and Mango, i.e. row by row.
MSE should take difference of `x` and `y` values of the year.
Basically, I need the total MSE for Apple and Mango respectively.

I know MSE can be calculated as-

```
MSE = np.mean((p['x'] - p['y'])**2, axis=1)
```

But how would I calculate for this type of data frame?

Comment: Could you detail it more with an example? Do you mean you would like to get MSE for Apple for year 2016,2017,2018?

Comment: @cody Thanks for letting me know. Its the a total MSE of Apple, not every year.

Comment: This would be easier if your data were organized with one row for predicted and one row for actual.  Do you have control over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the index to `Fruits` and transform the columns into a MultiIndex of `(x/y, year)`:

```
p = p.set_index('Fruits')
p.columns = p.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
p = p.swaplevel(axis=1) 

#         x               y          
#         2016 2017 2018  2016 2017 2018
# Fruits                                
# Apple   2    4    12    3    3    12
# Mango   3    5    13    4    4    13
```

Then the MSE arithmetic can be vectorized:

```
mse = p['x'].sub(p['y']).pow(2).mean(axis=1)

# Fruits
# Apple    0.666667
# Mango    0.666667
# dtype: float64
```

Note that chaining [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and [`pow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pow.html) is just a cleaner way of applying `-` and `**` on columns:

```
mse = ((p['x'] - p['y']) ** 2).mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Sure, makes sense, one quick question, in mse we do have a summation, I am not sure, where is the summation present in the equation?

Comment: MSE is a summation divided by the number of observations, i.e., the mean. Here we just use [pandas.DataFrame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) to get the mean per row (axis=1) in one step. You _could_ do it in a roundabout way with an explicit sum: `SE = p['x'].sub(p['y']).pow(2); MSE = SE.sum(axis=1).div(SE.columns.size)`